# random number generator java

Tags: java, android, random, butterknife

I'm trying to create a basic app in android to get a feel for android studio. I want it to produce a random number between 2 given inputs (high and low) and display that number in a list of the last 5. This is the code I have now, and as it currently works, it's setting 'low' to the high limit. I've racked my mind around this issue for a while and can't come up with an answer.

For example: I used 10 as low and 20 as high and the last 5 numbers it out put was 8, 9, 5, 0, and 8.

EDIT: per pjs request, I shortened the code to the necessities and ran a few more tests. I also added the print statements after the high and low in the OnClick function and this was my output.

setting low to 10 and high to 20 outputs
7 with a system out of 7 for high and low,
3 with a system out of 3 for high and low,
4 with a system out of 4 for high and low,
etc.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


    /**
     * Create all instance variables
     */
    int high, low, r;
    ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>(5);
    boolean firstNum = true;
    Random random = new Random();

    /**
     * Bind the IDs made in the xml with the objects being used in main
     * using butterknife
     */
    @BindView(R.id.lowestNum) EditText min;
    @BindView(R.id.highestNum) EditText max;
    @BindView(R.id.currentRando) TextView rando;
    @BindView(R.id.randoList) TextView randoList;
    @OnClick (R.id.genBtn)

    /**
     * Generates the random number for the user
     * @param view
     */
    @OnClick(R.id.genBtn)
    public void onClick(View view) {
        high = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());
        System.out.println(high);
        low = Integer.parseInt(min.getText().toString());
        System.out.println(low);
        r = random.nextInt(high - low + 1) + low;
        rando.setText("" + random);
        updateList(r);
        randoList.setText("" + listHelper(numList));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is `low` and `high` inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: In this case, the code is making them both be inclusive

Comment: have you checked that `max.getText()` and `min.getText()` are returning what you expect i.e. the upper & lower limits respectively?

Comment: Testing `r = random.nextInt(high - low + 1) + low;` specifically, it works as expected for me with `low=10` and `high=20`.  You may have an issue with what those two values are set to

Comment: I believe it's more of an issue with butterknife now thanks to Tom Mac. The getText() is returning the same number for both arguments. It appears that high and low are not even read into the program

Comment: A [**Minimal**, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be a good thing here.